# return specific Data using has Role

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My Code Here is Working Fine but although he is returning user Role in the return can i prevent user roles from returning it's belongs to relation using role_id in users Table

```
$paths = Path::with(['user','tags'])->where('category_id',1)->get();

foreach($paths as $path){

    if($path->user->hasRole('admin')){
        $AdminPaths [] = $path;
        }
    if($path->user->hasRole('user')){
        $UserPaths [] = $path;
        }
}

return  $UserPaths;
```

My User Model

```
class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
 {
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'username'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

}

Comment: I couldn't understand what are you trying to achieve. Do you mean return all paths with users but without showing the role_id attribute on User?

Comment: i;m returning  all paths created by Users type of admin and user and everything is ok but i'm getting role relation with user and idon't want this

Comment: Can we see your User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function `hasRole` from here:
https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.2/src/Traits/VoyagerUser.php

It executes `loadRolesRelations()` that loads the roles relationships and thats why users come with the role relation loaded.

You could just unset the role relation after checking the role like:

```php
foreach($paths as $path){

    if($path->user->hasRole('admin')){
        $AdminPaths [] = $path;
    }
    if($path->user->hasRole('user')){
        $UserPaths [] = $path;
    }
    unset($path->user->role);
}
```